# Should we use exit or return in child process

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, fork

Saying that I have used `fork` to create one child process. Here is an example:

```
pid_t pid=fork();
if (pid==0) /* child */
{
    // do something
    exit(0); // _exit, exit or return????
}
else /* parrent */
{
    wait(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I've seen many examples of `fork`. Some of them used `_exit` to terminate the child process to avoid flush the I/O buffer, others used `exit` to terminate the child process. But non of them used `return`. As my understanding, `_exit` and `exit` won't call destructors automatically, so is it better to call `return` instead of `exit` in the child process? Or because all examples that I've ever seen are C, instead of C++, so they don't need to worry about destructors?

Comment: Some consider returning from `main` as the only form of normal program termination while exiting or aborting it anywhere else is considered an abnormal termination. And it certainly is because it makes it difficult to reason about program control flow or track whether order of uninitialization is correct. Note that there are no destructors in C but it means that you must worry 10x times more because you need to perform all the uninitialization manually.

Comment: In C there is not difference in leaving `main()` via doing  a `return x;` or by calling `exit(x)`.

Comment: In C aside of doing this in `main()` `return`ing from a function or `exit()`ing the process indeed *is* different.

Comment: @alk but in C++ returning from main() or calling exit(3) is indeed different, as the OP correctly notices. But it's the destructors of automatic variables defined within main() which won't be called in case of exit(3), not the static/global variables, whose destructors will be called no matter if the program returns from main() or calls exit(3) explicitly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what destructors do you need to call on the way out whose jobs aren't already taken care of by process cleanup? Whenever a process exits, all of its memory is freed and all of its file descriptors are closed for you, even if you leaked memory or left files open.

Comment: I know this question was asked nearly two years ago, but when i read through the answers i have problems distinguishing the right from the wrong. On the other hand i think the question is really interesting for many. The uncertainty is partly due to a lack of votes (3 answers have 0 votes and one answer has -1 vote). Maybe there is someone who could bring clarity in this post? This would be really nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `_exit` or `exit`, but you shouldn't use `return`. When you fork a child, you retain the entire call stack as part of forking the child. So if you use `return`, you end up returning up all the way through your program, potentially continuing on and performing other tasks, which is almost certainly not what you want.

For example, if you have something like this snippet:

```
int get_value()
{
    pid_t pid;
    if (!(pid = fork())) {
        int x = 0;
        // do something with x.
        exit(x);
    }
    else {
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        return status;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int value = get_value();
    switch (get_value()) {
        case 0:
            // call f
            break;
        case 255 << 8:
            // call g
            break;
    }
}
```

you'll could end up calling `f` or `g` or doing other work with `return`, which is definitely not desired.

If you call `_exit`, functions that are registered with `atexit` are not called. This is the right thing to do in threaded environments. If you're not working in a threaded environment and you don't have any handlers registered with `atexit`, then they should be functionally equivalents.

If you want destructors in your child process to be called, put the child process code in its own function and let its variables be automatically destroyed when they go out of scope. `exit` will not destroy objects for you, which is good because usually you do not want to destroy objects created in the parent process in your child process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use return if you are looking for an exit code of the child process, just to say the process ran and executed correctly/not. Same as you do with your main function in a program. Otherwise just use exit to stop the process from running any further.

Comment: Please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090328/should-we-use-exit-or-return-in-child-process#comment98817361_56090328).

Answer (score -1):

`fork` will copy the whole process, its not equivalent to launching a thread with a new main function.
Returning will simply return from the current function and the execution of the child will continue in the enclosing function.

So in you snippet you have to terminate the child or it will "escape". You can do that by calling `exit()` or `std::terminate()`. No destructors are called in both cases. Don't mix two different languages.

If you really need to call the destructors in the child, throw an exception and catch it in main. That will unwind the stack correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Exit command should be avoid to use in any case except from ending the execution of the programme. For anything else, I would use return.